# jquery validation add inputs required dynamically

Tags: jquery, dynamic, jquery-validate

I am currently using the [bassistance jquery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) or the jqueryvalidation plugin(they renamed it) and I have it validating a form like so:

```
if($.fn.validate) {
        $("#frmNewOrder").validate({
            rules: {
                txtAmount: {
                    required: true,
                    digits: true
                },
                ddlAccount: {
                    required: true
                },
                ddlBank: {
                    required: true
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Now depending on the amount I need to require or not an extra field a dropdownlist and depending on that dropdownlist another text input. so it's like:

```
 if($('#txtAmount').val() >= 10000){
     //add ddlReason required
 }

 if($('#ddlReason').val() == 'o'){
     //add txtReason required
 }
```

I've tried adding the css class 'required' like the other fields but I take it if they are not inside the rules then it doesn't work?  I've tried adding rules like this:

```
 $( "#ddlReason" ).rules( "add", {
        required: true});
```

and that doesn't work either.  any suggestions?

EDIT:  Here's the [link](http://asantillan.com/jquery.validate.js) to the jquery validate that I'm using.  if I used rules outside it gives this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
```

on line 124:

```
var settings = $.data(element.form, 'validator').settings;
```

and using the suggestions I've seen in other places i've done this which is what causes the error:

```
var defaultrules = {
    txtAmount: {
        required: true,
        digits: true
    }
}

if($.fn.validate) {
    $("#frmNewOrder").validate();
    addRules(defaultrules);
}
```

EDIT 2: here's the html markup, hope it helps.

```
<form id="frmNewOrder" name="frmNewOrder" action="" method="post">
<label>Amount</label>
<input type="text" name="txtAmount" id="txtAmount" class="required" />
<button id="calculate" type="button">Calculate</button>
<div id="dvreason" style="display:none;">
    <select id="ddlReason" name="ddlReason">
         <option></option>
         <option value="i">Option 1</option>
         <option value="o">Other</option>
    </select>
    <div id="dvother" style="display:none">
       <label>Other reason</label>
       <input type="text" name="txtOther" id="txtOther" />
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post some HTML with the JS in context? Maybe put it in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I am having a hard time adding the validate on jsfiddle lol if I can figure it out I'll post it

Comment: No, you can certainly use `class="required"` or `.rules('add')` instead of within `rules` declaration in `.validate()`.  There must be something else wrong with your code. Show enough code for constructing a working demo.  All relevant jQuery and HTML.

Comment: I just added some more code and a link the the validate js file I'm using.

Comment: Still don't see enough code here for recreating your problem.  **Where is the HTML markup?**

Comment: I just added the html markup, and just as a personal opinion I see it really unfair to vote down my question and request to have it closed seeing how I put alot of info more than others have when asking.  And I always in all my questions shown all my effort and most of my code.  Not pointing fingers cause I don't know who to point to, but had to let it be known.

Comment: When you have a problem with jQuery Validation, you can set the property debug to true and see if you get any extra information. I received the same error message but my error was different, I was not calling "validate" method on the form but on the modal window. After changing that it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

faced similar issue with it,

in fact what you'll notice is that validator is undefined at line 124, i.e. there is no validator instance associated with the form

if you check the validate method you see that if validator is undefined it will create a new one

```
var validator = $.data(this[0], 'validator');
        if ( validator ) {
            return validator;
        }

        // Add novalidate tag if HTML5.
        this.attr('novalidate', 'novalidate');

            //HERE it is creating a new one using the constructor   
        validator = new $.validator( options, this[0] );
        $.data(this[0], 'validator', validator);
```

Apparently the `rules` method assumes that validator is already there in the form object, so from my understanding, and since `validate` returns validator instance, you can call `validate` and then append your extra rules to the returned validator `settings.rules` object and re-run again which is not very practical.

The other solution would be to simply append the added rules to the initial rules object before calling `validate`

So in my case I wanted the input field to be validated as number however I didn't want Google Chrome to make it a number field (just try  in Chrome to see what I mean,
this had the issue of bypassing the type number validation in case the user entered manually, and in my case the user will most probably enter the number manually)

code example:

```
var customRule = {number: true};

//suppose populateValidateRules() fills your initial rules, which is my case at least
var validationRules =  populateValidateRules();

validationRules["rules"].fieldToBeDynamicallyModifiedForValidation= customRule;

$(formId).validate(validationRules);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 10):

I'd gotten the same error message as well and realised that I should call the `validate()` on the form first before I call `rules()` on individual input fields. This behaviour is [documented](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules).

```js
$('#form').validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      email: true
    }
  }
});

$('#email').rules('add', {
  required: true
});
```

This may not be the answer to OP's problem, but I'm posting this to help anyone who searched `jquery validation Cannot read property settings of undefined` and clicked this page.

Thanks to the hint given by @[nsawaya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19528397/1762803)!

Comment: Thank you so much, this was a huge help!

Answer (score 0):

their is a problem while getting the dynamic add element using the id so it is working if you use attribute selector so for example add attribute `data="ddlReason"` and make it like this :

```
$( "input[data='ddlReason']" ).rules( "add", {
        required: true
});
```